# Is there any way to print **kwargs in Python

Tags: python

I am just curious about `**kwargs`. I am just started learning it, So while going through all the question on stackoverflow and video tutorials I notice we can do like this

```
def print_dict(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
print_dict(x=1,y=2,z=3)
```

Which gives output as :`{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}`
So I figures why not do the reverse and print the like `x=1,y=2,z=3`

So I tried this:

```
mydict = {'x':1,'y':2,'z':3}
print(**mydict)
```

But I got an error like : `TypeError: 'z' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`(sometimes it shows 'y' is an invalid keyword).

I also tried like assign it to the variable and then print it but again i got an error (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`):

```
mydict = {'x':1,'y':2,'z':3}
var = **mydict
print(var)
```

See this is working:

```
def print_dict(**this):
    print(this)
mydict = {'x':1,'y':2,'z':3}
print_dict(**mydict)
```

But instead of `print(this)` if i do `print(**this)` it gives the error.

As we can print `*arg` as I try this code:

```
def num(*tuple_num):
    print(tuple_num)
    print(*tuple_num)
num(1,2,3,4)
```

It run perfectly and gives output as:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
1 2 3 4
```

So I want to know is there any possible solution/way to print `**kwargs` ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The syntax `callable(**dictionary)` *applies* the dictionary as if you used separate keyword arguments.

So your example:

```
mydict = {'x':1,'y':2,'z':3}
print(**mydict)
```

Is internally translated to:

```
print(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

where the exact ordering depends on the current random hash seed. Since `print()` doesn't support those keyword arguments the call fails.

The other `print()` call succeeds, because you passed in the values as separate *positional* arguments:

```
tuple_num = (1, 2, 3, 4)
print(*tuple_num)
```

is effectively the same as:

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

and the `print()` function supports separate arguments by writing them out one by one with the `sep` value in between (which is a space by default).

The `**dictionary` is not valid syntax outside of a call. Since `callable(**dictionary)` is part of the call syntax, and not an object, there is *nothing to print*.

At most, you can *format* the dictionary to look like the call:

```
print(', '.join(['{}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in mydict.items()]))
```

Answer (score 31):

Using f-strings in python 3 works for me:

```
def mixAndMatch(*args, **kwargs):
    print(f' Args: {args}' )
    print(f' Kwargs: {kwargs}' )

mixAndMatch('one', 'two', arg3 = 'three', arg4 = 'four’)


>>>
Args: ('one', 'two')
Kwargs: {'arg3': 'three', 'arg4': 'four'}
```

Comment: With Python 3.8, this is clearly the simplest way to print your kwargs

Comment: This isn't really achieving anything the question didn't already achieve with `print(args)` and `print(kwargs)` (although the question didn't call it "args").

Answer (score 8):

You have to build your own formatting for dictionaries (nothing else are `**kwargs`):

```
print(','.join('{0}={1!r}'.format(k,v) for k,v in this.items()))
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty printing `kwargs` is easy with the `pprint` package:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(kwargs)
```

Example output from a call to `requests.get`:

```
{'allow_redirects': True, 'verify': False}
```